# How to find propagator for domain wall fermions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, lattice-model, lattice-gauge-theory

I am working on domain wall fermions right now and I am trying to understand how Luescher finds the propagator for the domain wall fermions in this review https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0102028 on pages 19ff.

I don't quit get the exact form of the proposed propagator and how it is able to solve the Dirac equaion.